# ASIHTTPRequest Basic Authentication failing

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, basic-authentication

I am using the following code:

```
NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"username\": \"%@\", \"password\": \"%@\", \"client_id\": \"%@\", \"client_secret\": \"%@\"}",
                    mFieldUsername.text, mFieldPassword.text, [NTDefaults clientId], [NTDefaults clientSecret]];
NSLog(@"Params:\n%@", params);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NTDefaults baseEndpointUrl] stringByAppendingString:@"/api/token.json"]];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",params.length]];
[request setAuthenticationScheme:(NSString *) kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic];
[request setUsername:@"user"];
[request setPassword:@"pass"];
[request setShouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge:YES];

[request setPostBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"Post Body: %@", request.postBody);
NSLog(@"Headers: %@", request.requestHeaders);
NSLog(@"URL: %@", url.absoluteString);
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Which is returning:

Error: Authentication needed

Does anybody have any ideas on this?  Successfully authenticated using ASIHTTPRequest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I successfully use:

```
request.shouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge = YES;
[request addBasicAuthenticationHeaderWithUsername:@"myUser"
                                      andPassword:@"myPass"];
```

I do not use setAuthenticationScheme for my basic authentication.

Comment: Thanks, I think this had more to do with the post body.  I'm now setting it with [request addPostValue:mFieldUsername.text forKey:@"username"]; etc.  Even so, your solution was also helpful...definitely worked.  Thanks!